Is there any sort of command-line tool I can use to detect and write metadata for a song's key?
I would like to get into DJing, or at least putting songs together in series and making it work. I have already used bpmwrap to tag the tempo for every song in my library, and it immediately made me realize that even when the tempo work is done for me, it's very hard for me to match the key. Is there any command-line tool for Linux that I can use to tag the key of every song in my library?
Edit: here is the text of the script that I wrote to analyze both key and tempo. You can modify it as necessary. I can clarify stuff if anyone needs it but I'm tired rn and won't do it now
#!/bin/bash
total=$(tree | grep .mp3 | wc -l)
declare -i count=0
echo -ne "Analyzing tempos... unknown/$total \r"
/home/spyndling/bigboy4tb/compiling/bpmwrap/bpmwrap.sh -w "/home/spyndling/bigboy4tb/Music imports/" > /dev/null
echo -ne "\033[2K"
echo "Tempos analyzed."
for f in ./**/**/*.mp3; do
    count+=1
    echo -ne "Analyzing keys... $count/$total \r"
    mid3v2 --TKEY "$(keyfinder-cli "$f")" "$f"
    echo -ne "\033[2K"
done
echo "Keys analyzed."


IMO you're going to hit music theory issues here. How do you tell the difference between C# major and Db major, for example - which one should be used as the tag? What about songs that switch between the relative major/minor? Or even songs that change key for the final verse/reprise (Celine Dion and Cliff Richard might we be talking about you?)

I simply don't care about the answers to any of these questions. I already mass-tagged tempo values for all four thousand tracks today and that has the same problems. As long as the results for the key analysis are as close to good as the results of the tempo analysis were, I am fine with anything.

How to write the metadata is easy with exiftool. Detecting the key: keyfinder-cli estimates the musical key.

This was a bit of an adventure, but I managed to get keyfinder-cli installed.You want to build these packages in this order.
Catch2-3.6.0.zip 
fftw-3.3.10.tar.gz 
libkeyfinder-2.2.8.tar.gz 
keyfinder-cli-main.zip 
Make a directory, build_temp is what I used, then download and extract them all into that folder.
Building Catch2:
sudo cmake -S . -B build

cd build
make
sudo make install


FFTW3 must be built using -fPIC to satisfy libkeyfinder's build.
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC --enable-shared
make
sudo make install


Building libkeyfinder:
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -S . -B build
cmake --build build --parallel
sudo cmake --install build


Build keyfinder-cli.
Very first thing, copy the libkeyfinder headers to /usr/local/include.
sudo mv /usr/bin/include/keyfinder /usr/local/include/

You can't just move ffmpeg's files like libkeyfinder's headers.
The easiest thing to do is copy them to /usr/local/include from the ffmpeg directory.
sudo cp /usr/include/ffmpeg/libavutil  /usr/local/include/
sudo cp /usr/include/ffmpeg/libavcodec /usr/local/include/
sudo cp /usr/include/ffmpeg/libavformat /usr/local/include/
sudo cp /usr/include/ffmpeg/libswresample /usr/local/include/

Go into the keyfinder-cli directory. The Makefile LDFLAGS have to be modified to include /usr/local/lib64. Replace it with the following:
PREFIX=/usr/local

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/local/include/keyfinder -I/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib64 -lkeyfinder -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswresample -lfftw3
TARGET = keyfinder-cli

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): keyfinder_cli.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

keyfinder_cli.o: keyfinder_cli.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

install: keyfinder-cli keyfinder-cli.1
    install -d "${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin"
    install -m 755 keyfinder-cli "${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/bin/keyfinder-cli"
    install -d "${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/share/man/man1"
    install -m 644 keyfinder-cli.1 "${DESTDIR}${PREFIX}/share/man/man1/keyfinder-cli.1"

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET)

Export the path: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Now, build keyfinder-cli:
sudo make
sudo make install


You should now have keyfinder-cli installed.

I'm very sorry that I never returned to this thread. Yes, this is the tool that I ended up using for this. Thank you
